# How to get live score of match with runs per ball of over without refresh page like cricbuzz using php or API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I had requirement to show updated score,runs per ball of over in my website so I had followed some tutorials on youtube ,so score which Iam getting in  xml file but that too updated score is getting after refresh page so i want update like cricbuzz.com implemented that way score, runs per ball so please help me how to do that using php i know upto this level so please guide me how to do this.

```
<?php 
$content=file_get_contents('http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml');


$x=new SimpleXmlElement($content);



 echo "<table border=1>";
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href=$entry->link target='_blank'>";
echo $entry->description;

echo "</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


?>
```

ouput:

[output which i am getting by using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyM1g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for live score you need socket connec5tion to api server which will send you live score on your php page. you are trying to use http call which is only single way.. for socket connection you can refer https://github.com/roanuz/php-cricket

or search `socket api for cricket score`

Comment: will it provide similar way like cricbuzz,so socket connection from which channel will provide ball by ball score

Comment: Yes it is socket, means persistent connection.  like whatsapp or fb messanger which will update every change which happens

Comment: thanks for your support and github link ,if you have one more easy way kindly suggest me, so I think I have to go through with node.js tutorials to learn socket.

Comment: For live notifications, no any way there apart `socket conn`  :(